# The meaning of the sentence

Tags: meaning

"Over three occasions, each of 3 nights, a total of 21,830 moths were collected, representing more than 1250 morphospecies." Especially ,the meaning of "each of 3 nights".

Comment: Each occasion consisted of a set of three nights. HTH.

Answer (score 3):

Each occasion was of three nights duration, so a total of nine nights were spent collecting the moths.

Comment: what is the meaning of "Over three occasions".three times or more than three time?

Comment: @user62161 *over* is used here in the sense of 'in a period of' as one might say 'extending over three days' to mean 'in a period of three days'. **over** *prep* **3**. during; through, or throughout (a period of time) http://www.thefreedictionary.com/over